# yowsup-celery How to run yowsup-celery in daemon mode passing whats app config file as argument

Tags: python, django, celery, daemon, yowsup

I am using:

yowsup-celery: https://github.com/jlmadurga/yowsup-celery

For trying to integrate whats app in my system.

I have been successfully able to store messages and want to now run celery in daemon mode rather than running in terminal

To run it normally we use:
    celery multi start -P gevent -c 2 -l info --yowconfig:conf_wasap

To run daemon mode we use:
    sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start

Here how can I pass config file as argument or is there a way to remove dependency of passing it as an argument rather reading the file inside script.

Comment: what distro are you running? how is celery installed? via system package manager? in virutal env? where did the init script come from?

Comment: @scytale in virtual env I am installing.
init file came as a standard method for declaring celery in daemon mode

Taken from ref:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858000/celery-in-daemon-mode

Answer (score 0):

Since version yowsup-celery 0.2.0 it is possible to pass config file path through configuration instead of argument.

`YOWSUPCONFIG = "path/to/credentials/file"`